# Group By Linq só retorna o campo Id

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

Tenho o seguinte método

```
public async Task<List<Fazenda>> GetAllFazendaTotal(int codigoTecnico)
    {
        var fazendas = await (from f in _apiBdContext.Fazendas
                              join a in _apiBdContext.Associados on f.CodigoAssociado equals a.Codigo
                              join pt in _apiBdContext.PaTecnico on a.CodigoPA equals pt.CodigoPA
                              where (pt.CodigoTecnico == codigoTecnico && f.Ativo == true)
                              group f by f.Codigo into p
                              select new Fazenda
                              {
                                  Codigo = p.Key,
                                  /*
                                  Ativo = f.Ativo,
                                  CodigoAssociado = f.CodigoAssociado,
                                  NomeFazenda = f.NomeFazenda == null ? "" : f.NomeFazenda,
                                  //NomeAssociado //Não se encontra na documentação do Bd, mas existe o campo no banco
                                  UF = f.UF == null ? "" : f.UF,
                                  CodigoIbgeCidade = f.CodigoIbgeCidade,
                                  AreaTotal = f.AreaTotal,
                                  TipoPosse = f.TipoPosse,
                                  ProprietarioTerra = f.ProprietarioTerra == null ? "" : f.ProprietarioTerra,
                                  RoteiroAcesso = f.RoteiroAcesso == null ? "" : f.RoteiroAcesso,
                                  Latitude = f.Latitude == null ? "" : f.Latitude,
                                  Longitude = f.Longitude == null ? "" : f.Longitude,
                                  Altitude = f.Altitude,
                                  */
                              }
                                )
                                .AsNoTracking()
                                .ToListAsync();


        return fazendas;
    }
```

Estou com problema na hora de retornar os dados, pois estavam vindo duplicados. Percebi que o problema era que estava faltando um group by, só que quando adiciono o group by não consigo retornar o resto dos campos, somente o Código que esta como key. Fiquei pesquisando como retornar esses campos que estão comentados, mas não achei nenhuma resposta que me ajudaria. Se alguém puder ajudar, sou iniciante e talvez esteja procurando errado.

Comment: *"ois estavam vindo duplicados. Percebi que o problema era que estava faltando um OrderBy"* order by não interfere nos duplicados só muda a ordem com que os dados são retornados, não seria um "group by" ?

Comment: Sim, é o group by, escrevi errado

Answer (score -2):

Você pode tentar adicionar o restantes dos campos dentro do `group by`:

```
group f by (Campo1, Campo2, Campo3)
```

Você pode verificar a [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

Assim como este [link com mais alguns exemplos](https://csharp.academy/linq-groupby/)